# User login monitoring tool

Tags: logging, monitoring

Our client has a Windows workgroup LAN with a UNIX/Oracle database server. We want a tool which can log login/logout details of network users to the database server. The problem is that we can't access the database server, although that would have been the easier solution, due to some company policy.

Below are some features needed for the tool:

1. LOG user login/logouts of network users( i.e. user name, ip address)
2. No workstation installation.
3. No domain only work group LAN

We considered the following options:

1. A proxy server in front of the database server. All traffic to the database server will pass through the proxy. But  how will the proxy will capture the network usernames of users trying to login? Any tool suggestion?
2. Switch port monitoring. But it will capture only the IP addresses of the users. How to capture the usernames/details?

Please suggest any tool or any other solution.

Comment: What kind of "login to the DB server" you need? To the console, X, or to the database server itself (what DB is that? PostgreSQL, MySQL, MongoDB...?)

Comment: @lserni to the database server itself, DB is Oracle

Comment: Logging database access should already be a part of your company policy. Ask for access to the user auditing capabilities that are built into Oracle. That really is the best answer, even if not convenient.

Comment: @schroeder I asked about it earlier, it is being maintained by some other company. However I will give lserni 's solution a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very easy to do that **passively**.

If the connection is not encrypted you might try adding a host "in front of" the database server, that will be able to intercept the Oracle conversations. A simple presentation [here](http://nyoug.org/Presentations/2008/Sep/Harris_Listening%20In.pdf).

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is able to intercept and decode traffic (user and machine), so that and some filtering script can intercept the connections themselves.

To be able to log other traffic statistics, you'd need to write a specific application using [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

That's all hacking, however. The "true" solution would be to work with the DB server accounting system. The hack version has the advantage of being passive, i.e. the server sees nothing amiss, and does not consume resources to perform logging and reporting; they are done in the sniffing "front end".

Comment: I will give your solution a try(Wireshark).